# ThreadPool executor and huge amount of clients connected simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm building a client-server application on Java with sockets. As far as I've understood to create a thread for every client being connected is too expensive. Instead we can use `ThreadPool Executor`. As said in the concurrent [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html?is-external=true) we can create a thread pool with a fixed size.

```
class NetworkService implements Runnable {
   private final ServerSocket serverSocket;
   private final ExecutorService pool;

   public NetworkService(int port, int poolSize)
       throws IOException {
     serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
     pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
   }

   public void run() { // run the service
     try {
       for (;;) {
         pool.execute(new Handler(serverSocket.accept()));
       }
     } catch (IOException ex) {
       pool.shutdown();
     }
   }
 }
```

And it seems we have at most `poolSize` thread running at every point of time. But what if we need to maintain a number of connection that is more than `poolSize`. How is it going to work?

Comment: It won't. Your clients will block until a thread is available.

Comment: Increase `poolSize`?

Comment: @ScottHunter I need, say, to maintain 1000 clients to be connected simultaneously. Does that mean I'm going to have to create 1000 threads?

Comment: There is a threshold for the pool size in Java (you can increase pool number but you won't have any gain). I don't remember the number.

Comment: @MladenUzelac so what is the solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957382/fixedthreadpool-vs-cachedthreadpool-the-lesser-of-two-evils

Comment: I hope you got your answer. I stumbled across very good article about ThreadPool and sizing: http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-Thread-Pool-Performance-Tuning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to have really **huge** amount of clients, you should consider **NIO** for it, because creating thread for each client will be too expensive.

NIO uses selectors and channels and doesn't require to create new thread for each connection. See [image](http://www.google.com.ua/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Ftutorials.jenkov.com%2Fimages%2Fjava-nio%2Foverview-selectors.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Ftutorials.jenkov.com%2Fjava-nio%2Fselectors.html&h=323&w=408&tbnid=s0S-x1oVXq4IOM%3A&zoom=1&docid=X4TGGKqEJfAX6M&ei=1KtoVJ2iNKPfywPXhoHQCQ&tbm=isch&ved=0CB8QMygAMAA&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=585&page=1&start=0&ndsp=20).

Did you hear about [netty](http://netty.io/) ? I don't know what you are going to implement but seems like it will be useful.

Comment: Ah, Ok... I've understood... more-or-less))

Comment: Well, I'm trying to implement a simple client-server massenger that can maintain around 500-1000 connection simultaneously.

Comment: I mean do you mean NIO would be necessary there?

Comment: 500-1000 it's far from huge :) nope, for your case would be enough just regular old blocking IO server , because it easier, but if your system will grow up... Author of book "Netty in Action" recommends to use NIO only for 1000+ concurrent connection. For example NIO server netty, can handle dozens or even hundreds of thousands concurrent connections.