# should ExecutorService be static and global

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I want to use the same thread pool throughout my application. To this end, I can make `ExecutorService` static and global so that I can invoke `ThreadUtil.executorService` to get `ExecutorService` when I need it.

```
public class ThreadUtil {
    public static final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
}
```

Is it OK to instance multiple  thread pools like this?

In addition, my application is a TCP server. If I don't know how big the pool should be, is it ok to simply use `newCachedThreadPool`?

Comment: Make sure you set the upper limit for number of threads when you use CachedThreadPool

Answer (score 6):

When an instance with the same properties is to be used anywhere in your program, it is logical to declare it static and final instead of re-creating the instance each time but I would personally opt for a Singleton pattern instead of directly giving public access to the instance.

As for your second query, I don't see any problem with it. The first sentence of the documentation for `newCachedThreadPool` says

> Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed

since you don't know how many threads will be created, this is the most logical choice.

Note that `newCachedThreadPool` will re-use old threads when they are available to increase performance.

Comment: Then, the service should not be shut down each time we put all needed tasks to it?

Answer (score 0):

I would not make it directly global. At least wrap it in a class so you can easily use more than one pool. Having a pool of thread pool is very useful when you need more than one kind of job/ jobs with different priority. Just put fewer threads in the other pool and/or lower priority threads (by over riding the thread factory). For a sample can see https://github.com/tgkprog/ddt/tree/master/DdtUtils/src/main/java/org/s2n/ddt/util/threads

Usage :

```
//setup
PoolOptions options = new PoolOptions();
options.setCoreThreads(2);
options.setMaxThreads(33);
DdtPools.initPool("poolA", options);
Do1 p = null;


  // Offer a job:
  job = new YourJob();
  DdtPools.offer("poolA", job);
```

Also do not use a cached pool as it can grow as needed, not a good idea with TCP which can block indefinately. You want to use a controlled pool. The above library can be reinitialized if needed (increase number of threads while allowing current jobs to process before the old pool is discarded to GC).

Can make a utility jsp/ servlet for those ops like https://github.com/tgkprog/ddt/blob/master/Core/src/main/web/common/poolEnd.jsp and https://github.com/tgkprog/ddt/blob/master/Core/src/main/web/common/threads.jsp

Answer (score 0):

If you have only ExecutorServivce for your application, you can proceed with static global.

`newCachedThreadPool()` and `newFixedThreadPool()` both does not provide control on queue of `Callable/Runnable` tasks. *They use unbounded queue*, which may result into degraded performance of the system with respect to performance.

I prefer to use [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) which provides better control on various parameters like *Queue Size, Rejection Handler, Thread factory* etc.

```
public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
                  int maximumPoolSize,
                  long keepAliveTime,
                  TimeUnit unit,
                  BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
                  RejectedExecutionHandler handler)
```

Or

```
public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
                  int maximumPoolSize,
                  long keepAliveTime,
                  TimeUnit unit,
                  BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
                  ThreadFactory threadFactory,
                  RejectedExecutionHandler handler)
```

Refer to below post for more details:

[FixedThreadPool vs CachedThreadPool: the lesser of two evils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957382/fixedthreadpool-vs-cachedthreadpool-the-lesser-of-two-evils)