# Java CachedThreadPool vs FixedThreadPool for multithreaded server

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a server that continually listens for client connections and creates a new thread each time a client connects to handle that client's I/O.  Right now, I have multiple classes that implement Runnable and have a while loop in the run method that keeps going until the client is closed.  I create a new Thread object and pass the runnable to that object.  I'm pretty sure there are other, more efficient ways to do this.  Should I switch to a cachedThreadPool or fixedThreadPool or something else?

Comment: Question duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957382/fixedthreadpool-vs-cachedthreadpool-the-lesser-of-two-evils/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to use the [`Executors#cachedThreadPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool--) if the size of clients isn't defined.

Documentation [`Executors#cachedThreadPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool--):

```
* Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but
* will reuse previously constructed threads when they are
* available.  These pools will typically improve the performance
* of programs that execute many short-lived asynchronous tasks.
* Calls to {@code execute} will reuse previously constructed
* threads if available. If no existing thread is available, a new
* thread will be created and added to the pool. Threads that have
* not been used for sixty seconds are terminated and removed from
* the cache. Thus, a pool that remains idle for long enough will
* not consume any resources.
```

Documentation [`Executors#fixedThreadPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-):

```
* Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads
* operating off a shared unbounded queue.  At any point, at most
* {@code nThreads} threads will be active processing tasks.
* If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active,
* they will wait in the queue until a thread is available.
```

So if you aren't sure that you exactly for example need 5 threads you shouldn't use the [`Executors#fixedThreadPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-).

Comment: Is there any problem with the fact that the client handling threads could be open for a long amount of time?  In the documentation for cachedThreadPool it says that they `will typically improve the performance of programs that execute many short-lived asynchronous tasks.`

Comment: `Threads that have not been used for sixty seconds are terminated and removed from the cache.` - Even if a thread is longer used it shouldn't be a problem.