# Override interrupt method for thread in threadpool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

Say I have this:

```
class Queue {
  private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

  public void use(Runnable r){
    Queue.executor.execute(r);
  }

}
```

my question is - how can I define the thread that's used in the pool, specifically would like to override the interrupt method on thread(s) in the pool:

```
   @Override 
    public void interrupt() {
      synchronized(x){
        isInterrupted = true;
        super.interrupt();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define how threads for the pool are created by specifying a [`ThreadFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html).

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1, new ThreadFactory() {
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new Thread(r) {
            @Override
            public void interrupt() {
                // do what you need
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Sure, a `ThreadFactory` can be expressed by a lambda.

```
ThreadFactory factory = (Runnable r) -> new YourThreadClass(r);
```

If there is no additional setup needed for a thread (like making it a daemon), you can use a method reference. The constructor `YourThreadClass(Runnable)` should exist, though.

```
ThreadFactory factory = YourThreadClass::new;
```

I'd advise reading the docs of [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html). They are pretty informative.

Comment: thanks..link to docs would be cool too, hard to find this! btw I assume newFixedThreadPool is what I am looking for, but theres also cachedThreadPool, cant figure out what that's about

Comment: @AlexanderMills https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949355/executors-newcachedthreadpool-versus-executors-newfixedthreadpool and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957382/fixedthreadpool-vs-cachedthreadpool-the-lesser-of-two-evils are good threads to read (to get the difference between these two)

Comment: Thanks a ton, you seem pretty knowledgeable on Java, this is a related question if you want to rake in some more points https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54564805/force-re-use-of-thread-by-completablefuture

Comment: @AlexanderMills happy to help, answered there